# Search for files that contain a string and list their names sorted by the modified date

Tags: files, grep, find, date, sort

I use this command to find all the file in a directory that contains a specific string:

```
grep -lir "string" path_to directory
```

Example

```
grep -lir "users" /var/www/mysite
```

This command displays all files in the specified directory that contain the string 'users'. However, I want to sort them by descending modification date; newest to the oldest.

Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First we use the `Z` option then at the other end xargs with -0 option will catch the file names and stat them, sort and remove the timing info to reveal a sorted newest first list.

```
 grep -Zlir users /var/www/mysite | xargs -0 -r stat --format='%Y+%n' | sort -t+ -k 1,1nr | cut -d+ -f2-
```

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
print -rl ./**/*(.De_'grep -qi "string" $REPLY'_om)
```

This uses [*glob qualifiers*](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) to select only the regular files  (`.`) that contain `string` (i.e. the glob results for which the expression `e_'grep -qi "string" $REPLY'_` returns `true`) and then via `om` sorts the final results by `mtime` (newest first). Remove the `D` if you don't want to search for hidden files.